# How can I convert an html5 web game to an android app?

Tags: unity, android, html5, porting

I have already made an html5 game and it is in service.
I want to service this at Android app too.
I know little about Java or Kotlin, so I think the least risky way is to use a webview.
There is already a function to save game data with Oauth authentication.
I thought this part should be replaced with google play Oauth.

However, there is a problem that the app does not run when the player is offline. (Run the app fails to load any html document)

However, if you load a local html file, it will be rejected from the existing firebase SDK because there is no domain.

In fact, I know very little about native app development, so I don't know that what I don't know, what I need.

What should I do in this situation?

Do I need to rebuild my app in Kotlin or Java from scratch?
Do I have to use the same engine as Unity?
Do I have to rebuild with a framework like cordova?

The question may not fit here, but I need help. Please.

Comment: Did you use our [search](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=html5+android)? Does anything there help?

Comment: thanks. i didnt found that when i search, :)

Comment: "However, there is a problem that the app does not run when the player is offline. (Run the app fails to load any html document) / However, if you load a local html file, it will be rejected from the existing firebase SDK because there is no domain." So you know where to keep hunting... Fix Firebase or replace it with something else?

Answer (score 3):

Your first step should typically be to simplify the app down to its simplest working version. Gut everything that is causing the app to fail to run on the new platform (comment it out OR put in mock/dummy functions or modules) and get the app into a basic working state.

Remove all non essentials: user authentication, ads, payments, leaderboards, social media linkage.

Aim to make the game runnable first on the **original** platform **without any integrations** (firebase etc.), then try run in WebView on Android...

...Then reintroduce all the stuff you disabled, one step at a time, until you have a working app on the **target** platform.

---

The reason you're doing this is that, before you start going down 999 rabbitholes that could cost you a lot of time, you need to know that the basic game, no frills, *can even be run at all on the target platform*. You're reducing risk, as early as possible.

Comment: I was planning it just now. thanks :)

Comment: This is why you should regularly try to build and run your game for all platforms you consider to support. The earlier you catch any platform-specific issues, the easier it gets to pinpoint which change exactly introduced them.